# Validating multiples input

Tags: java

I don't want the user to enter negative values. How can I detect negative values along with `InputMismatchException`? This is the code I have so far! The code does not seem to work right and can't figure out where the problem is. I want to validate the user input to make sure that negative numbers, strings and double are invalid and prompt the user to enter the right number, which should be a positive integer.

```
            do {
                try {
                    System.out.println("How many " + teaName + " did you today?");
                    if(input.hasNextInt() && (numberItem = input.nextInt()) > 0) {
                        istrue = false;

                        numberItem = input.nextInt();

                    }

                } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                    input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Please enter right number");
                    istrue = true;
                }
                catch (NoSuchElementException e){
                    System.out.println(" Please enter positive integers");
                }
            } while (istrue);
```

Comment: A negative number is not an exception thrown by `Scanner` so you can't add it to the `catch` block

Comment: Can you post your entire code?

Answer (score 0):

```
         do {
            try {
                System.out.println("How many " + teaName + " did you today?");
                if(input.hasNextInt()) {
                    if (numberItem = input.nextInt()) > 0) {
                        istrue = false;

                        numberItem = input.nextInt();
                    } else {
                        throw new InputMisMatchException("negative num");
                    }

                }

            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter right number");
                istrue = true;
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException e){
                System.out.println(" Please enter positive integers");
            }
        }while (istrue);
```

this should work, all I do is throw an InputMismatchException when the number is negative.

Comment: Using if statements to just `continue` the do while loop is actually faster than throwing an exception and catching it

Comment: Also, exceptions should not be used for routine flow control